# C# iTextSharp Chinese character extraction

Tags: c#, regex, string, unicode

So I am trying to extract Chinese words from a PDF.

I have the extraction working using iTextSharp, but once extracted, I find a gap/hidden space has been added in between the extracted characters. This is a huge problem because it breaks the characters into multiple space separated strings even though it should only be a single string.

I have tried various encodings, and they all create the same gap/hidden/added space. This usually happens with strings of 3 or more Chinese characters.

My goal is to extract the complete Chinese strings as shown below.
Any and all help is appreciated.

Sample data in PDF:
A请 B请请 C请请请 D请请请请 E请请请请请 F请请请请请请
1请 2请请 3请请请 4请请请请 5请请请请请 6请请请请请请
请 请请 请请请 请请请请 请请请请请 请请请请请请

```
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);

byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(currentText);
byte[] cleanbytes = ScrubBytes(bytes);

char[] chars = Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(bytes);                      

currentText="A 请 B 请请 C 请 请请 D 请 请请请 E 请 请请请 请 F 请 请请请请 请 \n1 请 2 请请 3 请请 请 4 请请 请请 5 请请 请请请 6 请请 请请请请 \n请 请请 请 请请 请请请 请 请请请请 请 请请 请请请 请 "
```

As you see, a gap has been added in the C and D, and 2 gaps have been inserted in E and F.

character array for content data listed below:

```
[0] 65 'A'  char
        [1] 32 ' '  char
        [2] 35831 '请'   char
        [3] 32 ' '  char
        [4] 66 'B'  char
        [5] 32 ' '  char
        [6] 35831 '请'   char
        [7] 35831 '请'   char
        [8] 32 ' '  char
        [9] 67 'C'  char
        [10]    32 ' '  char
        [11]    35831 '请'   char
        [12]    32 ' '  char
        [13]    35831 '请'   char
        [14]    35831 '请'   char
        [15]    32 ' '  char
        [16]    68 'D'  char
        [17]    32 ' '  char
        [18]    35831 '请'   char
        [19]    32 ' '  char
        [20]    35831 '请'   char
        [21]    35831 '请'   char
        [22]    35831 '请'   char
        [23]    32 ' '  char
        [24]    69 'E'  char
        [25]    32 ' '  char
        [26]    35831 '请'   char
        [27]    32 ' '  char
        [28]    35831 '请'   char
        [29]    35831 '请'   char
        [30]    35831 '请'   char
        [31]    32 ' '  char
        [32]    35831 '请'   char
        [33]    32 ' '  char
        [34]    70 'F'  char
        [35]    32 ' '  char
        [36]    35831 '请'   char
        [37]    32 ' '  char
        [38]    35831 '请'   char
        [39]    35831 '请'   char
        [40]    35831 '请'   char
        [41]    35831 '请'   char
        [42]    32 ' '  char
        [43]    35831 '请'   char
        [44]    32 ' '  char
        [45]    10 '\n' char
        [46]    49 '1'  char
        [47]    32 ' '  char
        [48]    35831 '请'   char
        [49]    32 ' '  char
        [50]    50 '2'  char
        [51]    32 ' '  char
        [52]    35831 '请'   char
        [53]    35831 '请'   char
        [54]    32 ' '  char
        [55]    51 '3'  char
        [56]    32 ' '  char
        [57]    35831 '请'   char
        [58]    35831 '请'   char
        [59]    32 ' '  char
        [60]    35831 '请'   char
        [61]    32 ' '  char
        [62]    52 '4'  char
        [63]    32 ' '  char
        [64]    35831 '请'   char
        [65]    35831 '请'   char
        [66]    32 ' '  char
        [67]    35831 '请'   char
        [68]    35831 '请'   char
        [69]    32 ' '  char
        [70]    53 '5'  char
        [71]    32 ' '  char
        [72]    35831 '请'   char
        [73]    35831 '请'   char
        [74]    32 ' '  char
        [75]    35831 '请'   char
        [76]    35831 '请'   char
        [77]    35831 '请'   char
        [78]    32 ' '  char
        [79]    54 '6'  char
        [80]    32 ' '  char
        [81]    35831 '请'   char
        [82]    35831 '请'   char
        [83]    32 ' '  char
        [84]    35831 '请'   char
        [85]    35831 '请'   char
        [86]    35831 '请'   char
        [87]    35831 '请'   char
        [88]    32 ' '  char
        [89]    10 '\n' char
        [90]    35831 '请'   char
        [91]    32 ' '  char
        [92]    35831 '请'   char
        [93]    35831 '请'   char
        [94]    32 ' '  char
        [95]    35831 '请'   char
        [96]    32 ' '  char
        [97]    35831 '请'   char
        [98]    35831 '请'   char
        [99]    32 ' '  char
        [100]   35831 '请'   char
        [101]   35831 '请'   char
        [102]   35831 '请'   char
        [103]   32 ' '  char
        [104]   35831 '请'   char
        [105]   32 ' '  char
        [106]   35831 '请'   char
        [107]   35831 '请'   char
        [108]   35831 '请'   char
        [109]   35831 '请'   char
        [110]   32 ' '  char
        [111]   35831 '请'   char
        [112]   32 ' '  char
        [113]   35831 '请'   char
        [114]   35831 '请'   char
        [115]   32 ' '  char
        [116]   35831 '请'   char
        [117]   35831 '请'   char
        [118]   35831 '请'   char
        [119]   32 ' '  char
        [120]   35831 '请'   char
        [121]   32 ' '  char
```

bytes below:

```
bytes   {byte[244]} byte[]
[0] 65  byte
[1] 0   byte
[2] 32  byte
[3] 0   byte
[4] 247 byte
[5] 139 byte
[6] 32  byte
[7] 0   byte
[8] 66  byte
[9] 0   byte
[10]    32  byte
[11]    0   byte
[12]    247 byte
[13]    139 byte
[14]    247 byte
[15]    139 byte
[16]    32  byte
[17]    0   byte
[18]    67  byte
[19]    0   byte
[20]    32  byte
[21]    0   byte
[22]    247 byte
[23]    139 byte
[24]    32  byte
[25]    0   byte
[26]    247 byte
[27]    139 byte
[28]    247 byte
[29]    139 byte
[30]    32  byte
[31]    0   byte
[32]    68  byte
[33]    0   byte
[34]    32  byte
[35]    0   byte
[36]    247 byte
[37]    139 byte
[38]    32  byte
[39]    0   byte
[40]    247 byte
[41]    139 byte
[42]    247 byte
[43]    139 byte
[44]    247 byte
[45]    139 byte
[46]    32  byte
[47]    0   byte
[48]    69  byte
[49]    0   byte
[50]    32  byte
[51]    0   byte
[52]    247 byte
[53]    139 byte
[54]    32  byte
[55]    0   byte
[56]    247 byte
[57]    139 byte
[58]    247 byte
[59]    139 byte
[60]    247 byte
[61]    139 byte
[62]    32  byte
[63]    0   byte
[64]    247 byte
[65]    139 byte
[66]    32  byte
[67]    0   byte
[68]    70  byte
[69]    0   byte
[70]    32  byte
[71]    0   byte
[72]    247 byte
[73]    139 byte
[74]    32  byte
[75]    0   byte
[76]    247 byte
[77]    139 byte
[78]    247 byte
[79]    139 byte
[80]    247 byte
[81]    139 byte
[82]    247 byte
[83]    139 byte
[84]    32  byte
[85]    0   byte
[86]    247 byte
[87]    139 byte
[88]    32  byte
[89]    0   byte
[90]    10  byte
[91]    0   byte
[92]    49  byte
[93]    0   byte
[94]    32  byte
[95]    0   byte
[96]    247 byte
[97]    139 byte
[98]    32  byte
[99]    0   byte
[100]   50  byte
[101]   0   byte
[102]   32  byte
[103]   0   byte
[104]   247 byte
[105]   139 byte
[106]   247 byte
[107]   139 byte
[108]   32  byte
[109]   0   byte
[110]   51  byte
[111]   0   byte
[112]   32  byte
[113]   0   byte
[114]   247 byte
[115]   139 byte
[116]   247 byte
[117]   139 byte
[118]   32  byte
[119]   0   byte
[120]   247 byte
[121]   139 byte
[122]   32  byte
[123]   0   byte
[124]   52  byte
[125]   0   byte
[126]   32  byte
[127]   0   byte
[128]   247 byte
[129]   139 byte
[130]   247 byte
[131]   139 byte
[132]   32  byte
[133]   0   byte
[134]   247 byte
[135]   139 byte
[136]   247 byte
[137]   139 byte
[138]   32  byte
[139]   0   byte
[140]   53  byte
[141]   0   byte
[142]   32  byte
[143]   0   byte
[144]   247 byte
[145]   139 byte
[146]   247 byte
[147]   139 byte
[148]   32  byte
[149]   0   byte
[150]   247 byte
[151]   139 byte
[152]   247 byte
[153]   139 byte
[154]   247 byte
[155]   139 byte
[156]   32  byte
[157]   0   byte
[158]   54  byte
[159]   0   byte
[160]   32  byte
[161]   0   byte
[162]   247 byte
[163]   139 byte
[164]   247 byte
[165]   139 byte
[166]   32  byte
[167]   0   byte
[168]   247 byte
[169]   139 byte
[170]   247 byte
[171]   139 byte
[172]   247 byte
[173]   139 byte
[174]   247 byte
[175]   139 byte
[176]   32  byte
[177]   0   byte
[178]   10  byte
[179]   0   byte
[180]   247 byte
[181]   139 byte
[182]   32  byte
[183]   0   byte
[184]   247 byte
[185]   139 byte
[186]   247 byte
[187]   139 byte
[188]   32  byte
[189]   0   byte
[190]   247 byte
[191]   139 byte
[192]   32  byte
[193]   0   byte
[194]   247 byte
[195]   139 byte
[196]   247 byte
[197]   139 byte
[198]   32  byte
[199]   0   byte
[200]   247 byte
[201]   139 byte
[202]   247 byte
[203]   139 byte
[204]   247 byte
[205]   139 byte
[206]   32  byte
[207]   0   byte
[208]   247 byte
[209]   139 byte
[210]   32  byte
[211]   0   byte
[212]   247 byte
[213]   139 byte
[214]   247 byte
[215]   139 byte
[216]   247 byte
[217]   139 byte
[218]   247 byte
[219]   139 byte
[220]   32  byte
[221]   0   byte
[222]   247 byte
[223]   139 byte
[224]   32  byte
[225]   0   byte
[226]   247 byte
[227]   139 byte
[228]   247 byte
[229]   139 byte
[230]   32  byte
[231]   0   byte
[232]   247 byte
[233]   139 byte
[234]   247 byte
[235]   139 byte
[236]   247 byte
[237]   139 byte
[238]   32  byte
[239]   0   byte
[240]   247 byte
[241]   139 byte
[242]   32  byte
[243]   0   byte
```

Comment: Try `Encoding.Unicode.GetString()` instead of `GetChar()` then process each char from there. Another test is to try encoding using `UTF8`.

Comment: So what makes a space valid versus invalid? In otherwords besides the invalid spaces you mentioned, will there *ever* be spaces in the result set?

Comment: So i think I have it worked out.. The process of saving a MS-Word doc as PDF doesn't allow the user to select Unicode* as a format. As such, my PDF was encoded using whatever MS Word uses, which was creating the downstream problem. When I save the file as .txt with the Unicode option, the code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Take the result and use regex replace to strip out any whitespace (tabs, spaces etc) such as:

```
string text = "A 请 B 请请 C 请 请请 D 请 请请请 E 请 请请请 请 F 请";

Console.WriteLine (Regex.Replace(text, @"\s+", string.Empty));

// Result printed out
// A请B请请C请请请D请请请请E请请请请请F请
```

Answer (score 0):

This question (and answer) are a bit old, but I'll add my solution here.

In the version of iTextSharp I'm using here in 2021 (5.5.13.2), using `PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage();` doesn't even work anymore.  I was processing a Japanese PDF, and all it extracted was linebreaks (/n) and bullets.

I was able to successfully extract text using this code (the same as the first 2 lines of code in the original question):

```
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
```

The only thing was, I had to change the font used in the PDF to **Meiryo UI** font.  If you use Meiryo UI font, iTextSharp's GetTextFromPage will successfully extract Chinese characters (as well as Japanese kanji, katakana and hiragana).